# How do I use cp -r to overwrite existing files on Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running the following commands in Ubuntu WSL leads to strange behavior - the file `text.txt` within the `dst` folder is not overwritten even though it should be.

```sh
mkdir temp
mkdir temp/src
mkdir temp/dst
echo "src" > ./temp/src/text.txt
echo "dst" > ./temp/dst/text.txt
cp -r ./temp/src/ ./temp/dst/
cat ./temp/dst/text.txt
```

Output

```
dst
```

The output SHOULD be `src`.

I've also tried the below:

```sh
sudo cp -Rfv ./temp/src/ ./temp/dst/
cat ./temp/dst/text.txt
```

Output

```
'./temp/src/text.txt' -> './temp/dst/src/text.txt'
dst
```

Answer (score 0):

Directory structure:

```
--temp
  --src
    --text.txt
  --dst
    --text.txt
```

After cp -r ./temp/src/ ./temp/dst/

Directory structure become：

```
--temp
  --src
    --text.txt
  --dst
    --text.txt
    --src
      --text.txt


so cat ./temp/dst/text.txt
ouput: dst
```